# What are the second effects of weapon enchantments?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

By enchanting a weapon with an elementary damage, around every 3 seconds this effect will deal additional second.

But there are also secondary enchantment effects. For example the fire damage weapon enchantment also places a small DoT on the enemy, which ticks for a few seconds. A desease enchantment also decreases the healing the afflicted enemy receives, but I'm not sure on the exact percantage reduced.

**Is there a known table of the secondary effects of the weapon enchantments?**